# Nginx SSL working but sending request as http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, https, digital-ocean

I followed [Deploying a Rails App on Ubuntu 14.04 with Capistrano, Nginx, and Puma](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma) to deploy a Rails app to Digital Ocean.

It suggested to keep **nginx.conf** (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/medical-app) as

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/myappuser/apps/medical-app/shared/tmp/sockets/medical-app-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /home/myappuser/apps/medical-app/current/public;
  access_log /home/myappuser/apps/medical-app/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/myappuser/apps/medical-app/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

and than I added domain and than installed **SSL** using **let's encrypt**
which changed the nginx.conf (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/medical-app) as following

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/myappuser/apps/medical-app/shared/tmp/sockets/medical-app-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /home/myappuser/apps/medical-app/current/public;
  access_log /home/myappuser/apps/medical-app/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/myappuser/apps/medical-app/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}

server {
  # server_name example.com;
  root /home/myappuser/apps/medical-app/current/public;
  access_log /home/myappuser/apps/medical-app/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/myappuser/apps/medical-app/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

    server_name www.medtib.com medtib.com; # managed by Certbot

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.medtib.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.medtib.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = medtib.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = www.medtib.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

  listen 80  ;
    server_name www.medtib.com medtib.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**Now https is working fine** but if I enable force SSL through Rails config

> config.force_ssl = true

Than it gives error page not working with message **redirected too many times**

and if I try to login with Facebook which requires https than it gives following error

[image: Try re-loading the page as https://]

I don't have idea about nginx etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should forward X-Forwarded-Proto header to your application to inform your application which protocol used. (https, http)

Put the following:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Before:

```
proxy_pass http://puma;
```

It should do the trick.

Comment: It tried it by adding but facefook saying same thing "Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://"

Comment: my bad, I had to do 'sudo service nginx restart' after those changes.